# Find ia a strn column is in a list column in the same data frame and create a 3rd column with a value

Tags: python, string, list, comparison, operator-keyword

I have this data frame with 2 columns, **"Column A" and "Column B"**, Column A is a string and column B is a list:

```
A        B                               c
cat      | cat | elephant | gorilla |    YES
dog      | monkey | duck | giraffe |     NO
bird     | cow | bird | hamster |        YES
```

and I want to evaluate **if Column A is in Column B** and if so to **write YES or NO in this new column C**

I tried many ways, the very last one is:

```
df_epl["Marketo LSC"] = df_epl["Data Entry Point"].isin("Entry Point List")
```

but it gives me this error:

in isin

```
raise TypeError(TypeError: only list-like objects are allowed to be passed to isin(), you passed a [str]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('res.csv') #Your csv here
C = []
for i in range(0,len(df)):
  if df['A'][i] in df['B'][i]:
    C.append('YES')
  else:
    C.append('NO')
df['C'] = C
print(df)
```

Comment: thanks a lot, a tried just as you said, but it gives this now this error:
if df['A'][i] in df['B'][i]: TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable

Comment: Can you please check the data type of second column in your data frame. If the above msg is true then the second column must be float but not list.